# Displaying and hiding images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a small animated effect with jquery in which images display and then hide one after the other.In my code all images display at once and then hide one by one. Please help out. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hide1").delay(2050).hide(1);
    $('.show1').delay(2000).show(1);
    $(".hide2").delay(2550).hide(1);
    $('.show2').delay(2500).show(1);
    $(".hide3").delay(2550).hide(1);
    $('.show3').delay(3000).show(1);
    $(".hide4").delay(3550).hide(1);
    $('.show4').delay(3500).show(1);
    $(".hide5").delay(4050).hide(1);
    $('.show5').delay(4000).show(1);

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="hide1" class="show1" style="position:absolute; top:300px; left:300px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="hide2" class="show2" style="position:absolute; top:260px; left:340px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="hide3" class="show3" style="position:absolute; top:220px; left:380px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="hide4" class="show4" style="position:absolute; top:180px; left:420px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="hide5" class="show5" style="position:absolute; top:140px; left:460px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="hide6" class="show6" style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:500px;" src="9.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

### EDIT

After getting suggestions I have made modifications. I have used hide but still it does not hide.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hide1").delay(2050).hide(1);
    $('.show1').delay(2000).show(1);
    $(".hide2").delay(2550).hide(1);
    $('.show2').delay(2500).show(1);
    $(".hide3").delay(2550).hide(1);
    $('.show3').delay(3000).show(1);
    $(".hide4").delay(3550).hide(1);
    $('.show4').delay(3500).show(1);
    $(".hide5").delay(4050).hide(1);
    $('.show5').delay(4000).show(1);
    $('.noshow').hide(0);


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="noshow hide1 show1" style="position:absolute; top:300px; left:300px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="noshow hide2 show2 " style="position:absolute; top:260px; left:340px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="noshow hide3 show3 " style="position:absolute; top:220px; left:380px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="noshow hide4 show4 " style="position:absolute; top:180px; left:420px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="noshow hide5 show5 " style="position:absolute; top:140px; left:460px;" src="9.png" />
<img class="noshow hide6 show6 " style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:500px;" src="9.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two class tags? Try `class="hide1 show1"`.

Comment: Check my answer below, I have updated it with a jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same image for all those `img` tags from which I am assuming you are trying to create a image flickr effect. For that you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.webegg.co.uk/flicker-effect-with-jquery/).

If you want you code to behave synchronously then you have to inserts each `show/hide` into another's complete callback like this

```
$(".hide1").delay(2050).hide(1,function(){
         $('.show1').delay(2000).show(1,function(){
              $(".hide2").delay(2550).hide(1);
        });
 });
```

Which will create a very big chain and not desirable. Check the above tutorials output at http://www.mattbudd.co.uk/  If you want something like that You can follow the tutorial.

Here's a possible solution to your problem if I am not mistaken

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/brQMX/)

Comment: Thanks but thats really not what I want. I am creating an animation in which a ball will move around the page.

Comment: Something like this: http://www.mattbudd.co.uk/ see the guy who moves in the image.

Answer (score 1):

They are shown together at first, because theres nothing written that would make them hide.
Yuo can add a "display:none" styling to them, if what u want them to do is to show/hide one bye one, or u can alter ur script to hide() all of them without any delay, and then add ur original code.

You also dont need the 2 differen css classes, as they dont affect the images in anyway